# error Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'SBMenu''

On my AppDelegate, I check if the user is connected and launch :

- a view controller with storyboard id 'SBLogin' if the user isn't already connected
- or a split view controller with storyboard id 'SBMenu' if the user is already connected

I use xcode 6.1.1, sdk 8.1, deployment target 7.0
On emulator iOS 8.1, all is fine and I'm not getting the error.
On emulator iOS 7.0.3 or 7.1, I'm getting the error

the code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//...

if(self.token != nil){
    //crash
    self.viewController = (UIViewController *)[mainSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBMenu"];
}else{
    //don't crash
    self.viewController = (UIViewController *)[mainSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBLogin"];
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

I already checked tips found on other post :

- only one story board
- only 'base' in localization
- storyboard ID correctly set
- test delete app from simulator before build
- clean project

Comment: Can you show your code that instantiates `mainSB`? And what shows under "Main Interface" in your target's "Deployment Info"? (Also, as well as checking the ID "SBMenu" of the view controller in Interface Builder, try actually deleting the ID and re-typing it, including hitting <kbd>return</kbd>, and re-building...)

Comment: From there docs: "An identifier string that uniquely identifies the view controller in the storyboard file. You set the identifier for a given view controller in Interface Builder when configuring the storyboard file. This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself and is only used by the storyboard file to locate the view controller." Did you set the identifier `SBMenu` in the viewController ?

Comment: @MattGibson code that instantiates mainSB : UIStoryboard *mainSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
under "Main Interface" : field is empty, when I set this to Main, I obtain "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?" -> entry point is not set because I want choose it.

Comment: @MattGibson I also test deleting, re-typing, hitting return, (also change in code and storyboard), delete app on emulator, clean, rebuild -> I get the same issue

Comment: @Zaph not the identifier but storyboard id, I read on some post : "pre xcode 4.4 Identifier, post xcode 4.5 Storyboard ID".

Answer (score 1):

`This will only work if you are using Storyboard(s).`

What you need to do is go into your storyboard, and find the view controller that is your "SBMenu" class.

Open the side panel, and find this:

[image]

Look for the box that says `Storyboard ID`. Make sure that your SBMenu class has SBMenu inside that box, and also check for your SBLogin class as well.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but with a UISplitViewController, after hours of search, I discovered that disabling the size classes, would solve this problem.